# How to use sendmail on docker

Tags: docker, smtp, docker-compose, sendmail

I use sendmail on docker with same configure local, but docker always raise error **connection refused**.

```
echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v xxx@mail.com
```

Results

```
Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

Ports:

```
0.0.0.0:25->25/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:587->587/tcp
```

Comment: do you have a smtp server running in the container?

Comment: @haschibaschi: No, just sendmail. Problem is my local still work

Comment: as I understand, sendmail tries to reach the smtp server on localhost, but there is none running. So you have to either run a smtp server in the container or provide the hostname of the smtp server to sendmail.

Comment: @haschibaschi: Why my local or vagrant don't occur this problem, just with container on docker

Comment: can't tell you that, just check if you have a smtp listening local or in vagrant.

Comment: @haschibaschi: thank you